# How do you get php to send an email

Tags: php

I have a frontend in flutter that sends data to update mysql database in php. The form sends the data and the database updated just fine. However, it is bypassing or ignoring the section to send mail. I am not getting any errors for the mail. What am doing wrong?

```
<?php
    
    require_once('dbc.php');
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email= $_POST["email"];
    $phone= $_POST["phone"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    
    
    $findexist="select * from registered where name='$name'";
    
    $resultsearch=mysqli_query($conn,$find-exist);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultsearch)>0) {
        
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultsearch)) {
            $result["success"] = "3";
            $result["message"] = "user Already exist";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registered (name,email,phone,password) VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$password');";
        
        if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
            $result["success"] = "1";
            $result["message"] = "Registration success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            

            $to = $email;
            $subject = 'Signup | Verification';
            $message = 'Thanks for signing up with redhowler!';
        
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
        
            $headers .= 'From: redhowler2@gmail.com'. "\r\n";
        
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            
            mysqli_close($conn);
      
        }
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: You need to configure SMTP

Comment: Pretty much all the details you've provided are irrelevant to your question. We don't care that you're accessing this from Flutter, and if the database insert is running OK, then that section of code is not "being ignored". Your actual [mre] would be the code from `$to = ...` to `mail(...); and your question, I presume, is why you don't **receive** the resulting e-mail.

Comment: `$find-exist` is an invalid variable name. Your code also is open to SQL injections. Parameterize and use prepared statements. The native PHP mailer function is not recommended. It has poor error reporting. Use Swift or PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHPMailer

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Username   = "xxxxxxxx@email.com";
        $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress($to, "recipient-name");
        $mail->SetFrom("xxxxxxxxx@email.com", "from-name");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("xxxxxxxxx@email.com", "reply-to-name");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($editor);




        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Error while sending Email.";
            var_dump($mail);
        } else {
            echo "Email sent successfully";
        }
```

Comment: Probably going to need more info than this. e.g. `PHPMailer.php`, `SMTP.php`, `Exception.php` for starters

Comment: malek, still not working. It wouldn't do anything. Once the insert query runs it is looking for json return. It ignores the mail section.

Comment: iif you using Gmail you need to give the application permission https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255   and composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: Malek, I download and move composer into my website folder. It is called PHPMailer. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am getting no errors. I need the best way to get this work. I read that if I am not getting any email most likely google block port 25. not sure that is true. I used to receive an email saying someone access or trying to access my account. Now I am not getting any acknowledgment. PHMailer isn't any difference. The same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up send mail on your computer. I didn't use PHPmailer. I used mail(). Nevertheless, you have to have some knowledge of UNIX or Linux script -- according to the operating system. You also have to search(like google search) for "how to setup send mail on mac (enter operating system)". Links such as those mention below helped me:

https://gist.github.com/haccks/7ec2fe500332a6d23ee68d1c1a2279d5

https://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#comment-87436